# Error using sym.int Too many input arguments

Tags: matlab

i ve searched some "Too many input arguments." questions but i have not found answer...

i am a newbie to matlab so i have the following problem

i want to integrate using principalvalue method but i get the folowing message

```
 syms w
 f2=(log(w)-log(1000))/(w^2-1000000)
 int(f2, w, 0, inf, 'PrincipalValue', true)
```

and i get :

```
Error using ==> sym.int
Too many input arguments.
```

What can i do to overcome this problem?

Comment: The code above runs on my system. Is `PrincipalValue` explained when you access your local documentation via `doc symbolic/int`? Maybe this feature is only available in recent versions.

Comment: no there is no exlpaination in the local documentation for this.Thank you . do you know if there is a way to get it ? with no instalation of a new ? i use 7.12.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of Matlab, 7.12.0, also known as R2011a, does not have the `'PrincipalValue'` functionality. The documentation for R2011a can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011a/index.html).

The value returned by my copy of Matlab for your integral is

```
(pi*243045032034301i)/70368744177664000 + pi^2/4000
```

However, using the command `integrate(log(x) - log(1000))/(x^2 - 1000000)) from 0 to infinity` with Wolfram Alpha yields only the real `pi^2/4000` component with no imaginary part. Additionally, Wolfram Alpha is not computing the principal value, as it appears that it is able to evaluate the indefinite integral at `w = 1000` as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28%28log%28x%29%20-%20log%281000%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%20-%201000000%29%20%29%20). This would mean that there is no need to compute the principal value as the ordinary integral exists, according to Wolfram Alpha. Matlab seems to disagree, as it computes a different antiderivative for `f2`.

If you want to try and compute principal values for other functions using your version of Matlab, the following script can work as a template (using the definition of a Cauchy Principal Value found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)):

```
syms w;
syms e;
syms b;
format long; % For long decimal display
f2=(log(w)-log(1000))/(w^2-1000000);
fake_inf = 5e60; % Really high number, gives NaN for true inf
% Cauchy Principal Value about w = 1000: compute as limit of a sum
integral1 = int(f2, w, 0, 1000-e);
integral2 = int(f2, w, 1000+e, fake_inf);

% Built-in Principal Value integral result:
% int(f2, w, 0, inf, 'PrincipalValue', true);
0.002467401100272 + 0.010850676618623i

CPV = limit(integral1+integral2, e, 0, 'right');
eval(CPV)
```

which outputs

```
ans =

  0.002467401100272 + 0.010850676618623i


ans =

  0.002467401100272 - 0.417381909829793i
```

where `0.002467...` is the decimal expansion of `pi^2/4000`. The antiderivatives computed by Matlab and Wolfram Alpha agree in their real arguments yet differ in their imaginary arguments (Wolfram Alpha has none).

Note that I use a '`fake_inf`' variable: Matlab cannot compute the integral if the true `inf` value is used.

Comment: Thank you so much.Your answer is THE BEST!. I try use a new vers cause i want to do that for 150 different constants so i ll try to make a loop with those hope it gonna work and not crash with 150 different functions :P